# Is it possible to use another values from annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I have the following annotation:

```
public @interface ExceptionPair {

    public Class<?> exception();

    public String message() 
         default "The following exception thrown:" + exception().toString(); 
        //error: not a constant
}
```

Are there some tricks to define a defult value using another value like in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

Default values must be constant, either primitives or Strings. As Strings are immutable in Java, in order to concatenate `exception().toString()` to the previous String, a new String must be created. Of course, creating new objects isn't a constant and therefore concatenation is not allowed. Additionally, since `exception().toString()` can change, the `default` value will *never* be constant.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible.

Annotation values are described in [JLS 9.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-ElementValue). The language isn't terribly clear, but basically the values have to be constants (or an "inline" array of constants):

> If T is a primitive type or String, then V is a constant expression (§15.28).

That doesn't preclude string concatenation, but the concatenated string does have to be a constant, as defined in [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). Since `exception().toString()` is not a constant (the result of a method is never a constant), neither is `"foo" + exception().toString()`.

The only trick you can really do is to designate some string that represents an empty message, and at the call site, if you see that string then return `"The following exception thrown:" + annotation.exception()` instead. The empty string `""` is a good candidate for that value (it can't be null, though).

Comment: for the normative reference. +1